# Как в шаблоне для ansible разбить строку и вставить дефисы?

Tags: ansible, шаблонизаторы, jinja2

Хочу на машинах настроить [syncthing](https://syncthing.net/). В конфиге есть `device id`, который представляет собой 8 групп по 7 символов. Что-то типа:

```
<device id="XP6UB5O-VIQ22NK-FOXOTX2-JAX3IH5-A4QXPN7-OPWKTGR-V5OD3AF-FHHBIQ4" introducedBy=""></device>
```

С идемпотентностью проблем не возникло [посчитал sha256 от хостнейма](https://ansibledaily.com/idempotent-random-number/), но возникла другая проблема: как строку, в которой нет разделителей разбить на равное количество символов и воткнуть дефисы?

На данный момент застрял на этом:

```
debug:
  msg: "{{ (ansible_hostname | hash('sha256'))[:56] | upper }}"

ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "1E6F2CDE48E942DAD8777183BC442F10F282C2F015C12405DD1091FF"
}
```

Comment: Device ID — это хэш самоподписанного сертификата, связанного с публичным ключом Syncthing. Вы не можете просто так взять и подставить какие попало символы, в том числе хэш от хостнейма.

Comment: Хм. А как тогда мне раскидать конфиг, если я его часть вообще не знаю?

Comment: Например, никак? Позволить Syncthing'у сгенерировать все сертификаты, конфиги и id при первом запуске и не париться? При втором запуске ничего генерироваться не будет, так что идемпотентность сохранится

Comment: Не. Я ж ещё и свой сервер обнаружения настроил. Потому что там, где это всё будет работать - инет порезан.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это будет из разряда программирования на Jinja2 фильтрах. Следите за руками!

```
---

- set_fact:
    host_hash: |-
      {{ (ansible_hostname
      | hash('sha256'))[:56]
      | upper
      | trim }}

- set_fact:
    sequence: |-
      {{ (ansible_hostname
      | hash('sha256'))[:56]
      | upper
      | trim
      | list }}

- set_fact:
     split_seq: |-
       {% for i in range(0, sequence|length, 7) %}
       {{ sequence[i:i+7]|join }}
       {% endfor %}

- debug:
    msg:
      - "{{ host_hash }}"
      - "{{ split_seq }}"
      - "{{ split_seq|trim|replace('\n', '-') }}"
```

Результат

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        "446FCF71E710AE084AD206FD45535269EDD7091EA834E13F8CA0538D",
        "446FCF7\n1E710AE\n084AD20\n6FD4553\n5269EDD\n7091EA8\n34E13F8\nCA0538D\n",
        "446FCF7-1E710AE-084AD20-6FD4553-5269EDD-7091EA8-34E13F8-CA0538D"
    ]
}
```

**Ссылки**

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9475241/split-string-every-nth-character

Comment: Оказалась типичная проблема молотка, но вопрос не закрывал, потому что мало ли - вдруг понадобится в другом месте при схожих обстоятельствах. Так что всё равно спасибо.